# Whatsapp active chat list item animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I was wondering if there is an easy way of creating the animation, similar to Whatsapp one.

When you are on chat screen and go back to chat list, an active element is highlighted gray for a moment (so it shows which chat was opened before).

Is there not complicated way of doing this in JS or CSS? Hopefully most of you guys know what I'm talking about. Unfortunately can't find any examples in the net...

Comment: Mhh. I see the effect your talking about, but ... where to put this ? Are you creating a chat app or something ? What do you need ? Do you have any code to show us ? You are too broad, please provide more details.

Comment: I don't know if any code would help. Let's say I can 'catch' the element with JQuery and add it the class `$(element).addClass('animation')`. Now, what would be more effective, CSS keyframes or just JavaScript? And how to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a example of how you could achieve the effect, but with no more details on your project i can't do more.

```js
var li = $('li');
var messages = $('.messages');
var close = $('.close');

li.on('click', function(){
  $(this).addClass('active');
  messages.addClass('active');
});

close.on('click', function(){
  messages.removeClass('active');
  li.removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.info {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  background: #ececec;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .2s .3s;
}


li.active {
  background: gray;
  transition: background .3s;
  
}

.messages {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  padding: 20px;
}

.messages.active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.close {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 70px;
  top: 30px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="info" >Click on a person, and close the discussion by clicking on the "X" to see the effect.</p>

<ul>
  <li>Bob</li>
  <li>Steven</li>
  <li>Marie</li>
  <li>Marc</li>
  <li>Jack</li>
  <li>Edouardo</li>
</ul>

<div class="messages">
  A lot of messages bla bla ...
  
  ...
  
  <span class="close">X</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Due to lack of information this is probably the best solution I can get. And it helped. Thanks again.